# Multiple activities through one java class file

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android application in which I have to create many activity files. the main screen consists of 3 buttons for each button for a new activity, so I want to go through each activity to switch to another activity.

This means that a button click switches to another activity, then scroll to more tasks to view the images and then scroll back to the main activity screen.
But I want my whole code only on a java class file. I do not want to create several java class files.

Thanks

Afzal

Comment: Having all code in one class is a bad idea. Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: `I want my whole code only on one java class ` that is bad code

Comment: Very bad idea...It's not a good practice

Comment: Is this some sort of assignment and you are required to use Activities? Otherwise, you should look into a ViewPager with Fragments instead, those are exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok i got its bad idea. Thanks. So I required separate class file for each activity.  I will create a main activity where i place 3 buttons. when i click a button it should redirect to a screen where image pasted then i want swipe to switch another activity upto last activity then again main activity screen.